# I can only use the ViewPager to page backward and can not page forward

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-banner

I can only use the ViewPager to page backward and can not page forward.

[running image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IVpf.gif)

I'm writint an banner,but I can only use the ViewPager to page backward and can not page forward.

This is the adapter I wrote.

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        int p = position % mImgRes.length;
        container.addView(mListView.get(p));
        return mListView.get(p);
    } 

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

}
```

This is an error message.

> ```
>    07-29 20:45:02.098 20791-20791/com.example.myfirstpro E/AndroidRuntime: 
>    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: com.example.myfirstpro, PID: 20791
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4465)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4301)
>        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1505)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4242)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4215)
>        at com.example.myfirstpro.MainFragment$MyPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(MainFragment.java:62)
>        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
>        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1216)
>        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
>        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:892)
>        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:704)
>        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:637)
>        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:878)
>        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5628)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
> ```

The program will crash when I roll forward.

This is in addition to the code other than the adapter.@Hong Duan

```
    private ViewPager mVpScroll;
private int mImgRes[] = new int[] {
        R.drawable.banner01,
        R.drawable.banner02,
        R.drawable.banner03
};
private List<View> mListView = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater mInfalte;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    for (int i = 0; i < mImgRes.length; i++) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_scroll_item, null);
        ImageView ivBanner = (ImageView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.iv_scroll);
        ivBanner.setImageResource(mImgRes[i]);
        mListView.add(inflate);
    }
    mInfalte = inflater;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mVpScroll = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp_scroll);
    mVpScroll.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());
}
```

Comment: You want to make only go one direction right ?

Comment: use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter`

Comment: See my this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389635/5743202

Comment: you have to inflate a view on `instantiateItem` and then add in the container but you adding view in the container which already has a parent.

Comment: Please show the code about `mListView` and `mImgRes`?

Comment: @HongDuan I have just written in the back.

Comment: @ThomasLee see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message shows, the root cause is a child `View` is added twice. But why this only happens when you swipe backward? I've made a test project and I think I find the reason :)

When `ViewPager` scrolls, it will recycle items using its `PagerAdapter`'s methods: `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem`, when `ViewPager` wants to show a new item, `instantiateItem` is called, when `ViewPager` scrolls away, the view which off the screen will be destroyed by method `destroyItem`.

By default, the `ViewPager` will keep **`1`** more item on each side for smooth scrolling, which means there are at most **`3`** items keep by the `ViewPager`.

The problem is, you are using:

```
int p = position % mImgRes.length;
```

to implement a "loop" `ViewPager`, that means if `mImgRes.length == 3`, the position 3 will show the same `View` at position 0.

Now think about your case:

- when `ViewPager` inited, the item `0` and `1`(right side item) are added by `instantiateItem`;
- then scroll right a page, the item `1` is shown, and the item `2` is added, now the item `0`(left side item), `1`, `2`(right side item) are kept;
- scroll right a page again, the item `2` is shown, the item `3` is added, the item `0` is destroyed by method `destroyItem`, now the item `1`(left side item), `2`, `3`(right side item, the same item to `0`) are kept;

Everything works fine if `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` work as expected, and it does work when you scroll to the right("forward"), but it does not work when you scroll to the left("backward") because the order of when `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` are executed is different! See the log:

```
07-30 22:00:04.385 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: instantiateItem: 0
07-30 22:00:04.388 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: instantiateItem: 1
07-30 22:00:17.693 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: instantiateItem: 2
07-30 22:00:18.743 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: destroyItem: 0
07-30 22:00:18.744 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: instantiateItem: 3
07-30 22:00:26.477 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: instantiateItem: 0  < -- crash!!!
07-30 22:00:18.743 26064-26064/com.example.test D/xxxxx: destroyItem: 3
```

when you scroll to the right, `destroyItem` executed first, then `instantiateItem`, so it works fine, but when you scroll to the left, `instantiateItem` executed first, so when the last line of log printed, the item `0` is added the second time, because the item `3`(which share the same `View` with item `0`) has not been destroyed yet, then it crashes :)

The interesting thing is that if `mImgRes.length > 3`, it will work fine, because when there are 4 items, it's not too late when `destroyItem` execute.

So, if you want to implement `ViewPager` with the "loop" feature, you have to think about how to work around this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much now that I know where it is wrong.I can write code like this can be a loop.`private int mImgRes[] = new int[] {
            R.drawable.banner01,
            R.drawable.banner02,
            R.drawable.banner03,
            R.drawable.banner01,
            R.drawable.banner02,
            R.drawable.banner03
    };`